# Please change the recaptcha link to ensure the site is accessible in China

Tags: feature-request, captcha, china

Stack Overflow currently uses a recaptcha script hosted on `www.google.com`. This domain is inaccessible in China.

In a section about using recaptcha globally, Google's own [developer FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-use-recaptcha-globally) says:

> Yes, please use "www.recaptcha.net" in your code in circumstances when "www.google.com" is not accessible.

Therefore, can Stack Overflow please change the source of its recaptcha script to `www.recaptcha.net` in order to ensure that the site is accessible in China and other places that block Google?

If you are trying to test this yourself, note that you need to specify the full path to the script (`https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js`). If you just try to visit `www.recaptcha.net`, you will get a 404 error.

Comment: Um, I was thinking the exact same thing just when reCAPTCHAs became mandatory for searching here while logged out. It seems that in the meantime, China [began blocking access to that domain](https://viewdns.info/chinesefirewall/?domain=recaptcha.net). So unfortunately, that hack no longer works.

Comment: > China began blocking access to that domain. The site is not accurate. The 203.208.x.x IP is right for China's DNS, it's Google's cache server in Beijing, providing limited service for Chinese users. These services is on translate.google.cn, www.google.cn, ssl.gstatic.com, safebrowsing.google.com, dl.google.com etc.

Comment: And they also have the ability to provide service as recaptcha.net.

Comment: that api.js goes on and loads `https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/T9w1ROdplctW2nVKvNJYXH8o/recaptcha__en.js` for me by the looks of it. Will it do the same in China and gstatic.com isn't blocked?

Comment: Yes, `www.gstatic.com` is accessible in China. As `nslookup www.gstatic.com 1.2.4.8` returns also 203.208.x.x IPs. (P.S. 1.2.4.8 is CNNIC's DNS server)

Comment: Well, in China the `api.js` loads `https://www.gstatic.CN/recaptcha/releases/T9w1ROdplctW2nVKvNJYXH8o/recaptcha__en.js`, and `www.gstatic.CN` is definitely accessible.

Comment: I wonder why there was never an official response n here? Maybe the question should have status-review.